Select n rows from a data frame with the maximum dispersal
I have a data frame like this:
df <- data.frame(a = runif(100, -10, 10),
                 b = runif(100, -10, 10),
                 c = runif(100, -10, 10),
                 d = runif(100, -10, 10),
                 e = runif(100, -10, 10))

Now, I'd like to have a function that extracts n rows with the maximum dispersal.
To explain a little better, imagine a one-dimensional data set like c(1:9). The function I am looking for would be something like fun(3, c(1:9)) (with n=3) and return c(1, 5, 9). fun(5, c(1:9)) would return c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9).
A valid result for fun(3, c(1:10)) would be c(1, 5, 10) or c(1, 6, 9). In that case, the function should randomly select one of the valid outputs.
A while ago, I wrote this:
voronoiFilter <- function(occ, select){
  n <- nrow(occ) - select
  subset <- occ
  dropped <- rep(NA, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    v <- voronoi.mosaic(x = subset[,1], y = subset[,2], duplicate = "remove")
    info <- cells(v)
    areas <- unlist(lapply(info,function(x) x$area))
    smallest <- which(areas == min(areas, na.rm = TRUE))
    dropped[i] <- which(occ[,1] == subset[smallest,1] & occ[,2] == subset[smallest,2])
    subset <- subset[-smallest,]
  }
  outVec <- 1:nrow(occ)
  return(outVec[-dropped])
}

where occ is the input data frame and selected is n.
This sometimes works OKish, but often I receive this error:
Warning in hist.default(i, plot = FALSE, freq = TRUE, breaks = seq(0.5,  :
  argument ‘freq’ is not made use of

I think because there are duplicated elements in the data.
Does anybody have another idea, how such a function could look like?

EDIT
Apparently, the word dispersal has caused some confusion. So I will try to be more precise:
From an x*y matrix (or data frame) with numeric values, where x are rows and y > 1 are columns, find the n row-indices with the maximum euclidean distance between the respective rows within the y-dimensional space.

Another approach could be to use kmeans to identify n clusters. Which points within those clusters qualify as maximally dispersed will depend on your definition.

That could be a starting point. The problem with clustering is that I only want very few elements. In my current case the data set is a 246:6 matrix and n will be 3,4 or 5. If I create 3,4 or 5 cluster, each of them will contain many elements with quite some within cluster variation.

Dispersion could mean multiple things. Can you define your version mathematically?

Somewhat similar to the kmeans approach (not sure if even identical) is to calculate e.g. the Euclidian distance between all n relevant values and select those m values that lead to the minimum averaged distance. The problem with these approaches is that they are computational heavy since you need to calculate the distance between all combinations of values that exist.

In fact, I think of "dispersion" as maximizing distances between points. But calculating all of them by brute force is computationally not feasible. I was hoping that there is a smarter way to do that. Maybe this is more of a mathematical than a programming question.

Two questions: do you want to maximize the distance across several columns or just one? And if the latter: how many unique values will you most likely have? If you just have one column with e.g. 100 unique values, calculating the distances between all combinations of unique points shouldn‘t be any problem for a normal computer, so this would still be an option.

Can you expand your desired output for the 2-dimensional case (i.e. two columns instead of one)?

Be careful using technical terms like "dispersal" and "dispersion", which are very different words. They can't be used interchangeably. If dispersion is variance, then c(1,5,9) has the minimum dispersion among 3-tuples where the pool is 1:9. However, it has the maximum dispersal, defined as the spread or coverage of the data (the OPs desired output).

@deschen Right now, I have 246 rows with 6 columns. I usually imagine the entities (=rows) in a coordinate system with 6 dimensions, where each entity's position is defined by its 6 column values. However, I may have more rows and/or columns in the future.

"euclidean distance" is a pair-wise measure, say, between two N-dim points. If you have more than 2 points, what do you mean "maximize" here? do you maximize the sum of all  "euclidean distances" of selected n points? Better to give a numeric example to show how you calculate and the expected output as well.

This is an ongoing research problem. In fact, the methods given so far involve SA, TA and DE algorithms with regards to obtaining the domain optimum. You can use greedy search although its computationally infeasible for larger N

I have no idea how you define "dispersal", but I hope below code could give you some hints.
Assuming variance is applied as the measure of "dispersal", you can define a recursive function f like below
f <- function(S, v = range(S), n = 5) {
    if (length(v) == n) {
        return(v)
    }
    S <- S[!S %in% v]
    idx <- which.max(colSums(abs(outer(v, S, `-`))^2))
    Recall(S[-idx], n = n, v = sort(c(S[idx], v)))
}

and the output looks like
> set.seed(0)

> (S <- rnorm(10))
 [1]  1.262954285 -0.326233361  1.329799263  1.272429321  0.414641434
 [6] -1.539950042 -0.928567035 -0.294720447 -0.005767173  2.404653389

> f(S, n = 3)
[1] -1.539950 -0.928567  2.404653

and we can verify that the above output maximizes the variance
> combn(S, 3)[, which.max(combn(S, 3, var))]
[1] -1.539950 -0.928567  2.404653


That works for a one dimensional data set (or a matrix, but this matrix is still treated as a vector). I have a matrix with 6 columns. Each row represents an entity within the 6-dimensional space. The function should pick the n entities (rows, preferably by row index) that maximize the distance (that is what I call dispersal) between the n entities within this 6-dimensional space.

@Laas please give a math definition of "dispersal"
